# Could I get a clarification to this Python code below?

Tags: python, python-3.x, angle

I'm a beginner to Python and I'm trying to calculate the angles (-26.6 &18.4) for this figure below and so on for the rest of the squares by using Python code.

[image: Angle range]

I have found the code below and I'm trying to understand very well. How could it work here? Any clarification, please?

## Python Code:

```
def computeDegree(a,b,c):
    babc = (a[0]-b[0])*(c[0]-b[0])+(a[1]-b[1])*(c[1]-b[1])

    norm_ba = math.sqrt((a[0]-b[0])**2 + (a[1]-b[1])**2)
    norm_bc = math.sqrt((c[0]-b[0])**2 + (c[1]-b[1])**2)
    norm_babc = norm_ba * norm_bc

    radian = math.acos(babc/norm_babc)
    degree = math.degrees(radian)
    return round(degree, 1)

def funcAngle(p, s, sn):
    a = (s[0]-p[0], s[1]-p[1])
    b = (sn[0]-p[0], sn[1]-p[1])
    c = a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0]

    if p != sn:
        d = computeDegree(s, p, sn)
    else:
        d = 0

    if c > 0:
        result = d
    elif c < 0:
        result = -d
    elif c == 0:
        result = 0
    return result

p = (1,4)
s = (2,2)
listSn= ((1,2),(2,3),(3,2),(2,1))

for sn in listSn:
    func(p,s,sn)
```

The results

I expected to get the angles in the picture such as -26.6, 18.4 ...

Comment: Which angle are you trying to calculate? Its not very easy to read from your question.

Comment: @sandes My dear. It's not a matter of game. It's a serious matter. I'm not playing, I'm learning and I want to solve a problem in my work-study. I really need to understand this piece of code.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I need to understand this piece of code, when I do the calculation in hand, I found it is different.

Comment: Could you show how you called the functions, what results you expected (show your work) and what result you actually got?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, this uses the definition of dot products to solve for the angle. You can read more it at [this link](http://sharetechnote.com/html/Handbook_EngMath_Matrix_InnerProduct.html) (also where I found these images).

[image: Vector Graph]

To solve for the angle you first need to convert your 3 input points into two vectors.

```py
# Vector from b to a
# BA = (a[0] - b[0], a[1] - b[1])
BA = a - b

# Vector from b to c
# BC = (a[0] - c[0], a[1] - c[1])
BC = c - b
```

[image: Dot Product Formulas]

Using the two vectors you can then find the angle between them by first finding the value of the dot product with the second formula.

```py
# babc = (a[0]-b[0])*(c[0]-b[0])+(a[1]-b[1])*(c[1]-b[1])
dot_product = BA[0] * BC[0] + BA[1] * BC[1]
```

Then by going back to the first definition, you can divide off the lengths of the two input vectors and the resulting value should be the cosine of the angle between the vectors. It may be hard to read with the array notation but its just using the Pythagoras theorem.

```py
# Length/magnitude of vector BA
# norm_ba = math.sqrt((a[0]-b[0])**2 + (a[1]-b[1])**2)
length_ba = math.sqrt(BA[0]**2 + BA[1]**2)

# Length/magnitude of vector BC
# norm_bc = math.sqrt((c[0]-b[0])**2 + (c[1]-b[1])**2)
length_bc = math.sqrt(BC[0]**2 + BC[1]**2)

# Then using acos (essentially inverse of cosine), you can get the angle
# radian = math.acos(babc/norm_babc)
angle = Math.acos(dot_product / (length_ba * length_bc))
```

Most of the other stuff is just there to catch cases where the program might accidentally try to divide by zero. Hopefully this helps to explain why it looks the way it does.

**Edit**: I answered this question because I was bored and didn't see harm in explaining the math behind that code, however in the future try to avoid asking questions like 'how does this code work' in the future.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I will take into consideration your advice. Thank you so much, my dear.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with `funcAngle` since it calls computeDegree later.

The first thing it does is define `a` as a two item tuple. A lot of this code seems to use two item tuples, with the two parts referenced by `v[0]` and `v[1]` or similar. These are almost certainly two dimensional vectors of some sort.

I'm going to write these as  for the vector and vₓ and vᵧ since they're probably the two components.
[don't look too closely at that second subscript, it's totally a y and not a gamma...]

`a` is the vector difference between `s` and `p`: i.e.

```
a = (s[0]-p[0], s[1]-p[1])
```

is aₓ=sₓ-pₓ and aᵧ=sᵧ-pᵧ; or just =- in vector.

```
b = (sn[0]-p[0], sn[1]-p[1])
```

again;  =-

```
c = a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0]
```

c=aₓbᵧ-aᵧbₓ; `c` is the cross product of  and  (and is just a number)

```
if p != sn:
    d = computeDegree(s, p, sn)
else:
    d = 0
```

I'd take the above in reverse: if  and  are the same, then we already know the angle between them is zero (and it's possible the algorithm fails badly) so don't compute it. Otherwise, compute the angle (we'll look at that later).

```
if c > 0:
    result = d
elif c < 0:
    result = -d
elif c == 0:
    result = 0
```

If c is pointing in the normal direction (via the left hand rule? right hand rule? can't remember) that's fine: if it isn't, we need to negate the angle, apparently.

```
return result
```

Pass the number we've just worked out to some other code.

You can probably invoke this code by adding something like:

`print (funcangle((1,0),(0,1),(2,2))`

at the end and running it. (Haven't actually tested these numbers)

---

So this function works out a and b to get c; all just to negate the angle if it's pointing the wrong way. None of these variables are actually passed to computeDegree.

so, computeDegree():

```
def computeDegree(a,b,c):
```

First thing to note is that the variables from before have been renamed. `funcAngle` passed s, p and sn, but now they're called a, b and c. And the note the order they're passed in isn't the same as they're passed to funcAngle, which is nasty and confusing.

```
babc = (a[0]-b[0])*(c[0]-b[0])+(a[1]-b[1])*(c[1]-b[1])
```

babc = (aₓ-bₓ)(cₓ-bₓ)+(aᵧ-bᵧ)(cᵧ-bᵧ)

If ' and ' are - and - respectively, this is just

a'ₓc'ₓ+a'ᵧc'ᵧ, or the dot product of ' and '.

```
norm_ba = math.sqrt((a[0]-b[0])**2 + (a[1]-b[1])**2)
norm_bc = math.sqrt((c[0]-b[0])**2 + (c[1]-b[1])**2)
```

`norm_ba` = √[(aₓ-bₓ)² + (aᵧ-bᵧ)²] (and `norm_bc` likewise).

This looks like the length of the hypotenuse of ' (and ' respectively)

```
norm_babc = norm_ba * norm_bc
```

which we then multiply together

```
radian = math.acos(babc/norm_babc)
```

We use the arccosine (inverse cosine, cos^-1) function, with the length of those multiplied hypotenuses as the hypotenuse and that dot product as the adjacent length...

```
degree = math.degrees(radian)
return round(degree, 1)
```

but that's in radians, so we convert to degrees and round it for nice formatting.

---

Ok, so now it's in maths, rather than Python, but that's still not very easy to understand.

(sidenote: this is why descriptive variable names and documentation is everyone's friend!)